# Proving a set is a Sigma Algebra

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of a set $X$, and let $Y$ be an arbitrary subset of $X$. Let $B= \{ A\cap Y | A \in D \}$. Show that $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $Y$.

If we let $A=X$, then clearly $Y \in B$.

Suppose $G \in B$. Show $G^c \in B$.

So $G = A\cap Y$ for some $A \in D$.

So $G^c = A^c \cup Y^c$

I'm stuck here! Not sure how to show $G^c \in B$

Let $G1,G2,G3,.... \in B$. Not sure how to show that the infinite union of the $G_i$'s is an element of $B$.

Comment: Recent duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/596905/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $Y$ belongs to $B$ is clear for what you have said.
Let $G\in B$. This implies that there exists an $F\in D$ such that $G=F\cap Y$. Because $D$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$, we have that $X\setminus F\in D$. Now, because we want to show that $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $Y$ we have to check that $Y\setminus G$ belongs to $B$. Now,
$$
Y\setminus G= Y\setminus(F\cap Y)= Y\setminus F= Y\cap (X\setminus F)
$$
And the last equality implies that $Y\setminus G\in B$ by definition of $B$.
Now, if we let $\{G_n\}$ be a sequence of sets in $B$ and $G_n= Y\cap F_n$, $F_n\in D$ for every positive integer $n$, then
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (Y\cap F_n)=Y\cap( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n)
$$
And, again, because $D$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n\in D$ so $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n\in B$.

Comment: I edited your post to fix the infinities that weren't part of the limits for your unions.

Comment: Thanks! The key for this problem is assuming that A is a sigma algebra. However, I'm not sure how the problem warrants such assumption. Is it true that we can assume a subset of a sigma algebra to be a sigma algebra also?

Comment: Also, it might be trivial but G^c= U\G but U in this case is Y.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the original $\sigma$- algebra was called $D$ instead of $A$. I'll correct it.